# Continuous integration server for continuous deployment on Java/Spring web project

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, hudson, maven-3, continuous-deployment

I currently use maven to build, run unit tests and deploy my Java/Spring website locally.  I then run selenium functional tests and run through a whole long script to deploy to production and make schema changes.  I now want to automate everything so I can only hit a button and, as long as all tests pass, the production environment gets updated.

So it seems I can do all this in maven through plugins or at least with the ant plugin.  But there are many continuous integration servers available...  I hear a lot about Hudson.  Hudson manual states, "One of the main uses cases for Hudson is building projects with Apache Maven."  Is Hudson the best choice for what I need?  Is there a better solution?  I understand Jenkins was forked from Hudson, is it a better route?

I don't mind paying for a tool or server aiding in continuous deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with Jenkins. It is under active development, has tons of plugins and it's quite easily configurable. You might also want to check [Bamboo](http://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo/), especially if you would like it to work with Jira, Confluence, Fisheye, etc.

Comment: Wow, Jenkins' releases are very active!  They seem to have a new release every week.  So given the more active state and tons of plugins, Jenkins is more popular now than Hudson?  I love that they have a book coming out shortly...

Comment: Jenkins is much more active and probably also popular than Hudson. Hudson was renamed to Jenkins after some issues with the trademark. So the developers basically renamed the project to Jenkins, but Oracle still continued developing Hudson, though as of today the number of Jenkins member project members is much higher.